How to disable Preview popups from LSP server?
I use clangd as my LSP server and configure it with .clangd file. I don't use any additional LSP plugins. And every time I use the omnifunc on a function from any header except stdio.h and stdlib.h, it creates this annoying window:
Stackoverflow: Your post is mostly images. Add additional details to explain the problem and expected results.

When the system complains that your post is mostly images, why the  heck would you copy that text into your question instead of replacing the image with text? Check [ask], then [edit] your question accordingly.

I had nothing to add. Should I replace it with random text? Or should I give people a clue why that is there?

How the heck can I replace the image with text? What explains my question better than an image?

Isn't this the same issue as the one here? https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/38203/nvim-lspconfig-omnifunc-opens-preview-window

The default value for completeopt option (list of options for Insert mode completion) is "menu,preview" (see :help completeopt).
You could check your configuration for this option via verbose set completeopt?.
To disable preview in this popup, configure this option without it: vim.opt.completeopt = { "menu" }
